# GCP Dataflow warning message RMI TCP "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am running apache beam java pipeline and for some reason getting lots of warning logs in GCP.
I tried changing log level of packages java.net,sun.rmi to SEVERE but still no success.
Logs are getting polluted with these warning messages. Any one else facing the same issue ?

```
   jsonPayload: {
  exception: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:551)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:519)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:394)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:366)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
"   
  logger: "sun.rmi.transport.tcp"   
  message: "RMI TCP Accept-5555: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=5555] throws"
```

Pipeline is simple : Pubsub to Postgres. No additional third party connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to public documentation about [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshooting-your-pipeline).

Select the job to view more detailed information on errors and run results. When you select a job, you can view the execution graph as well as some information about the job. Then, click the Logs button to view log messages generated by your pipeline code and the Dataflow service.

Another thing, that you can use is debug option. When running the gcloud command, you can include the option `--verbosity=debug` to get debugging output.

This might be related to a JVM bug. Please check Java SDK version snd upgrade to a newer (`2.17.0` or higher) version.

Additionally, check `Encoding errors, IOExceptions, or unexpected behavior in user code` [error](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors).

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out the actual issue but in the mean time since it was polluting the logs traces added flag in pipeline options:

```
--workerLogLevelOverrides={"sun.rmi.transport.tcp":"OFF"}
```